# Why am I receiving a `Request must not be null` exception when calling getSessionAttribute()?

Tags: java, servlets, request, httprequest, portlet

Why am I receiving the following error from my code?

> Error 500: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request must not be null

**Code Snippet**

```
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map modelo, Document document, PdfWriter pdfWriter, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{

    // The problem is here to pass HttpServletRequest to ActionRequest or PortletRequest
    ActionRequest aRequest = (ActionRequest) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.request");

    // I need to validate user's session
    Cliente cliente = (Cliente) PortletUtils.getSessionAttribute(aRequest, AtokConstante.CLIENTE_SESION,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
}
```

Comment: Well you don't have a request attribute with key `javax.portlet.request`. For an attribute to be in the request attributes, you need to put it there. Do you do that?

Comment: Is the only solution? Where i have to put that i'm new in java.. One question i can do this: request.getAttribute(HttpServletRequest) or is invalid?

Comment: It won't do what you want. Where should the `ActionRequest` be coming from?

Comment: I should be coming from the HttpServletRequest because is the only object i get like input in my method or anothe way to cast HttpServletRequest to ActionRequest or RenderRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Without a stack trace on your exception, I suspect your variable `aRequest` is `NULL`.  This means the attribute `"javax.portlet.request"` has not been set in the `HttpServletRequest request` Object.  You are likely passing this null `aRequest` to `PortletUtils.getSessionAttribute()`, which is throwing the exception.

Without any other code to go on, I can only recommend that you investigate the lifecycle of `request` prior to your `buildPdfDocument()` method and ensure that either your expected value is saved at key `javax.portlet.request`, or that you are using the correct key String in the first place.